# Rotate Point3D around Unit Vector

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, quaternions

as an Image above

[image]

i want to rotate the point **P1** around unit vector **RotationAxis** (Red vector in Image and its in Center).

in my program (WPF) i Have a Quaternion and a 3DPoint.

How can i rotate the Point **P1**?

i tried Matrix rotation but it rotates nothing.

```
Matrix3D matrix = Matrix3D.Identity;
matrix.Rotate(RotationAxis); //RotationAxis is Quaternion
matrix.Transform(point3D); // point3D is Point3D that i want to rotate around RotationAxis
```

Comment: Have you looked into [QuaternionRotation3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.quaternionrotation3d.aspx)?

Comment: i looked at it.i try it now. @Xavier

Comment: Solved! the problem was that i didnt saved the point3D after calling matrix Transform ! anyway thanks for the comment ill look into it so it can be usefull in future, see the edit! @Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didnt save the result of Matrix Transform

```
point3D = matrix.Transform(point3D); // now point3D rotates as it should be
```